# How to follow a user using the TweetSharp API

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

I'm using the TweetSharp API, and I need to follow people in a C# `List`, however, I'm having trouble. The appropriate code is as follows:

```
var results = service.Search(new SearchOptions {Q = hashtag}); //hashtag string entered by user
List<decimal> users = new List<decimal>();

foreach (var tweet in results.Statuses)
{
    users.Add(tweet.User.Id);
}

foreach (decimal user in users)
{
    service.FollowUser(user);  //follow each user, the issue is here. 
}
```

Apparently I am using invalid arguments.

Comment: Then, apparently, you need to fix that. If you want us to help, posting the exact error would be helpful.

Comment: It's just saying I'm using invalid arguments, more specifically, "The best overloaded method match for 'TweetSharp.TwitterService.FollowUser(TweetSharp.FollowUserOptions)' has some invalid arguments." I'm fairly certain I'm using this correctly, so I'm just wondering if you have any ideas. Apologies for being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The `FollowUser` method takes a `FollowUserOptions` type as an argument, not a decimal. Try this:

```
foreach (var user in users)
{
    var options = new FollowUserOptions
    {
        UserId = user
    };

    service.FollowUser(options);
}
```